# perform browser action using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-scraping

I know using `http` I can remotely send request and get the data on a specified site like google.com. But how to use node to perform browser action, like go to google.com, use the input bar and perform click event on the site?

Comment: What is the purpose of that? This sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: @Amberlamps for example I want to do a bot that post status on facebook, but without using their API.

Comment: But why? This is exactly what the api is for.

Comment: @Amberlamps some sites doesn't provide API, so I plan to use the UI + bot to do it.

Comment: Looks like you are looking for selenium aka web driver.

Answer (score 0):

See `cheerio`, `phantomjs` or search npjmjs.com for 'scrape' 'browser automation' or 'headless'.

Comment: why not just use the `request` module?